# Generate separate elements based on date

Tags: xml, xslt

can someone help me how can I make this code

```
<pi:Employee>
<pi:Summary>
    <pi:Employee_ID>100000</pi:Employee_ID>
    <pi:Name>Test Name</pi:Name>
    <pi:Payroll_Company_ID>101</pi:Payroll_Company_ID>
    <pi:Payroll_Company_Name>Test Payroll Company</pi:Payroll_Company_Name>
    <pi:Pay_Group_ID>01</pi:Pay_Group_ID>
    <pi:Pay_Group_Name>Regular</pi:Pay_Group_Name>
</pi:Summary>
<pi:Personal />
<pi:Leave_of_Absence>
    <pi:Operation>ADD</pi:Operation>
    <pi:On_Leave>1</pi:On_Leave>
    <pi:Leave_Start_Date>2017-07-19</pi:Leave_Start_Date>
    <pi:Estimated_Leave_End_Date>2017-07-21</pi:Estimated_Leave_End_Date>
    <pi:Leave_Last_Day_of_Work>2017-07-18</pi:Leave_Last_Day_of_Work>
    <pi:Leave_Reason>LEAVE_TYPE_REASON-6-19</pi:Leave_Reason>
</pi:Leave_of_Absence>
```

become like this

```
<pi:Employee>
<pi:Summary>
    <pi:Employee_ID>100000</pi:Employee_ID>
    <pi:Name>Test Name</pi:Name>
    <pi:Payroll_Company_ID>101</pi:Payroll_Company_ID>
    <pi:Payroll_Company_Name>Test Payroll Company</pi:Payroll_Company_Name>
    <pi:Pay_Group_ID>01</pi:Pay_Group_ID>
    <pi:Pay_Group_Name>Regular</pi:Pay_Group_Name>
</pi:Summary>
<pi:Personal />
<pi:Leave_of_Absence>
    <pi:Operation>ADD</pi:Operation>
    <pi:On_Leave>1</pi:On_Leave>
    <pi:Leave_Start_Date>2017-07-19</pi:Leave_Start_Date>
    <pi:Estimated_Leave_End_Date>2017-07-19</pi:Estimated_Leave_End_Date>
    <pi:Leave_Last_Day_of_Work>2017-07-18</pi:Leave_Last_Day_of_Work>
    <pi:Leave_Reason>LEAVE_TYPE_REASON-6-19</pi:Leave_Reason>
</pi:Leave_of_Absence>
<pi:Leave_of_Absence>
    <pi:Operation>ADD</pi:Operation>
    <pi:On_Leave>1</pi:On_Leave>
    <pi:Leave_Start_Date>2017-07-20</pi:Leave_Start_Date>
    <pi:Estimated_Leave_End_Date>2017-07-20</pi:Estimated_Leave_End_Date>
    <pi:Leave_Last_Day_of_Work>2017-07-18</pi:Leave_Last_Day_of_Work>
    <pi:Leave_Reason>LEAVE_TYPE_REASON-6-19</pi:Leave_Reason>
</pi:Leave_of_Absence>
<pi:Leave_of_Absence>
    <pi:Operation>ADD</pi:Operation>
    <pi:On_Leave>1</pi:On_Leave>
    <pi:Leave_Start_Date>2017-07-21</pi:Leave_Start_Date>
    <pi:Estimated_Leave_End_Date>2017-07-21</pi:Estimated_Leave_End_Date>
    <pi:Leave_Last_Day_of_Work>2017-07-18</pi:Leave_Last_Day_of_Work>
    <pi:Leave_Reason>LEAVE_TYPE_REASON-6-19</pi:Leave_Reason>
</pi:Leave_of_Absence>
```

As you notice, from 1 root of Leave_of_Absence, it became 3. This must depend on the number of days that employee is on leave. On the example, Leave_Start_Date is from 2017-07-19 to 2017-07-21 and that makes it 3 days so there must be also 3 Leave_of_Absence roots. But elements of Leave_Start_Date and Estimated_Leave_End_Date must reflect the inclusive days.
Is there a way to do this? can someone help me? Thank you so much!

Comment: Is that at least XSLT 2.0 you can use to make use of XPath 2.0 date/dateTime arithmetics?

Comment: Hi Martin, yes it is XSLT 2.0.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In XSLT 2.0 you can use the `xs:date` data type and date arithmetic together with durations:

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
    exclude-result-prefixes="xs"
    xpath-default-namespace="http://example.com/pi"
    version="2.0">

    <xsl:output indent="yes"/>
    <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

    <xsl:template match="@* | node()" mode="#all">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()" mode="#current"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="Leave_of_Absence">
        <xsl:variable name="this" select="."/>
        <xsl:for-each select="0 to days-from-duration(xs:date(Estimated_Leave_End_Date) - xs:date(Leave_Start_Date))">
            <xsl:apply-templates select="$this" mode="day">
                <xsl:with-param name="date" tunnel="yes" select="xs:date($this/Leave_Start_Date) + xs:dayTimeDuration('P1D') * ."/>
            </xsl:apply-templates>
        </xsl:for-each>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="Leave_Start_Date | Estimated_Leave_End_Date" mode="day">
        <xsl:param name="date" tunnel="yes"/>
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:value-of select="$date"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Transforms

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<pi:Root xmlns:pi="http://example.com/pi">
    <pi:Employee>
        <pi:Summary>
            <pi:Employee_ID>100000</pi:Employee_ID>
            <pi:Name>Test Name</pi:Name>
            <pi:Payroll_Company_ID>101</pi:Payroll_Company_ID>
            <pi:Payroll_Company_Name>Test Payroll Company</pi:Payroll_Company_Name>
            <pi:Pay_Group_ID>01</pi:Pay_Group_ID>
            <pi:Pay_Group_Name>Regular</pi:Pay_Group_Name>
        </pi:Summary>
        <pi:Personal />
        <pi:Leave_of_Absence>
            <pi:Operation>ADD</pi:Operation>
            <pi:On_Leave>1</pi:On_Leave>
            <pi:Leave_Start_Date>2017-07-19</pi:Leave_Start_Date>
            <pi:Estimated_Leave_End_Date>2017-07-21</pi:Estimated_Leave_End_Date>
            <pi:Leave_Last_Day_of_Work>2017-07-18</pi:Leave_Last_Day_of_Work>
            <pi:Leave_Reason>LEAVE_TYPE_REASON-6-19</pi:Leave_Reason>
        </pi:Leave_of_Absence>
    </pi:Employee>
</pi:Root>
```

into

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<pi:Root xmlns:pi="http://example.com/pi">
   <pi:Employee>
      <pi:Summary>
         <pi:Employee_ID>100000</pi:Employee_ID>
         <pi:Name>Test Name</pi:Name>
         <pi:Payroll_Company_ID>101</pi:Payroll_Company_ID>
         <pi:Payroll_Company_Name>Test Payroll Company</pi:Payroll_Company_Name>
         <pi:Pay_Group_ID>01</pi:Pay_Group_ID>
         <pi:Pay_Group_Name>Regular</pi:Pay_Group_Name>
      </pi:Summary>
      <pi:Personal/>
      <pi:Leave_of_Absence>
         <pi:Operation>ADD</pi:Operation>
         <pi:On_Leave>1</pi:On_Leave>
         <pi:Leave_Start_Date>2017-07-19</pi:Leave_Start_Date>
         <pi:Estimated_Leave_End_Date>2017-07-19</pi:Estimated_Leave_End_Date>
         <pi:Leave_Last_Day_of_Work>2017-07-18</pi:Leave_Last_Day_of_Work>
         <pi:Leave_Reason>LEAVE_TYPE_REASON-6-19</pi:Leave_Reason>
      </pi:Leave_of_Absence>
      <pi:Leave_of_Absence>
         <pi:Operation>ADD</pi:Operation>
         <pi:On_Leave>1</pi:On_Leave>
         <pi:Leave_Start_Date>2017-07-20</pi:Leave_Start_Date>
         <pi:Estimated_Leave_End_Date>2017-07-20</pi:Estimated_Leave_End_Date>
         <pi:Leave_Last_Day_of_Work>2017-07-18</pi:Leave_Last_Day_of_Work>
         <pi:Leave_Reason>LEAVE_TYPE_REASON-6-19</pi:Leave_Reason>
      </pi:Leave_of_Absence>
      <pi:Leave_of_Absence>
         <pi:Operation>ADD</pi:Operation>
         <pi:On_Leave>1</pi:On_Leave>
         <pi:Leave_Start_Date>2017-07-21</pi:Leave_Start_Date>
         <pi:Estimated_Leave_End_Date>2017-07-21</pi:Estimated_Leave_End_Date>
         <pi:Leave_Last_Day_of_Work>2017-07-18</pi:Leave_Last_Day_of_Work>
         <pi:Leave_Reason>LEAVE_TYPE_REASON-6-19</pi:Leave_Reason>
      </pi:Leave_of_Absence>
   </pi:Employee>
</pi:Root>
```